# blank image capture with opencv threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-multithreading, circular-buffer

I am trying to write the frame captured from my laptop camera in to a circular buffer. I wanted to create a thread to handle this task (in an asynchronous way). When i try to get the last frame stored with `get_last()` method and show it, black screen is displayed. I have spent quite some time figuring out the reason, but all in vein. IMHO there should be a small issue with this code, but cannot see it. Any help will be highly appreciated. Complete working code is shown below:

```
import cv2
import sys
import time
import threading

class CamBuffer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, stream=0):
        self.current = 0
        self.max_size = 5
        self.buffer = [None] * self.max_size
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(stream)
        if not self.capture.isOpened():
            print("Could not open video")
            sys.exit()

        print("Opened video")
        self.running = True
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print('running thread')
        while self.running:
            print('capturing frame ', self.current)
            _, frame = self.capture.read()
            if _:
                print('saving frame ', self.current)
                self.buffer[self.current] = frame
                self.current = self.current + 1
                if (self.current >= self.max_size):
                    self.current = 0
        self.capture.release()
        print('stopped thread')

    def terminate(self):
        print('terminating thread')
        self.running = False

    def get_last(self):
        current = 0
        if self.current > 0:
            current = self.current - 1

        print('get_last()', current)
        return self.buffer[current]
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Frame buffer test')
    stream = 0
    cb = CamBuffer(stream)
    cb.start()
    time.sleep(1.25)

    frame = cb.get_last()
    if frame is not None:
        print('showing frame')
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    time.sleep(3)
    cb.terminate()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    print('Frame buffer test [Done]')
```

Comment: You are obliged to call `cv2.waitKey()` after `cv2.imshow()` because it uses that time to update the display - I found I needed at least 30 as the parameter to `cv2.waitKey()` some while back on macOS so maybe start with 30. You should not be calling `time.sleep()` in your code anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution that worked for me was just to add `cv.waitKey(1)` after imshow:

```
 if frame is not None:
        print('showing frame')
        cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1):
```

I think that's an issue with Opencv highgui module - it's a GUI and has its own thread, too, sometimes it could hang the application. The gray screen appears when trying to update a Highgui window/cv2.imshow() too quickly, I've encountered it in C++ as well. I guess something about locking the memory of the GUI thread and the image.

BTW, you could also add waiting in the capturing thread (if you don't need maximum framerate).

**PS.** Before realizing it could be solved with that line, I experimented with other possible issues: a lock.acquire/release, a global buffer, sending a buffer container as a parameter. However the global also was showing gray screen (although during the capturing it displayed captured images). It finally worked with buffer sent as a parameter, when I added cv2.waitKey(...) and I realized that it may be enough anyway.

#### The other experiments:

```
import cv2
import sys
import time
import threading

max_size = 5
buffer = [None] * max_size
frCopyGlobal = None
buff = [None] * max_size #call as param


class CamBuffer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, buff, stream=0):
        self.current = 0
        self.max_size = 5
        self.buffer = [None] * self.max_size
        self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(stream, apiPreference=cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
        if not self.capture.isOpened():
            print("Could not open video")
            sys.exit()

        print("Opened video")
        self.running = True
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        print('running thread')
        
        while self.running:        
            #lock.acquire()
            print('capturing frame ', self.current)
            _, frame = self.capture.read()
            cv2.imshow("F", frame)
            if _:
                #print('saving frame ', self.current%self.max_size, self.current)
                print('saving frame ', self.current)                
                frCopy = frame.copy()
                self.buffer[self.current] = frCopy
                
                frCopyGlobal = frame.copy()
                buffer[self.current] = frCopyGlobal                
                
                buff[self.current] = frame.copy()
                
                #self.buffer[self.current%self.max_size] = frame
                #cv2.imshow("FBUFF", self.buffer[self.current%self.max_size])
                cv2.imshow("FBUFF", self.buffer[self.current])
                cv2.imshow("GLOBAL BUFF", buffer[self.current])
                cv2.imshow("Param BUFF", buff[self.current])
                self.current = self.current + 1
                if (self.current >= self.max_size):
                    self.current = 0
            cv2.waitKey(66)
            #lock.release()
        self.capture.release()
        print('stopped thread')

    def terminate(self):
        print('terminating thread')
        self.running = False

    def get_last(self):
        current = 0
        if self.current > 0:
            current = self.current - 1

        print('get_last()', current)
        for i in self.buffer:
          cv2.imshow("THREAD: "+str(i), i)
        for i in buffer:
          cv2.imshow("GLOBAL: "+str(i), i)
        return self.buffer[current]
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lock = threading.Lock() #threading.Lock lock();
    print('Frame buffer test')
    stream = 0    
    cb = CamBuffer(buff, stream) # The buffer must be in common memory in order to read it from the calling thread
    cb.start()
    time.sleep(1.0)
    for i in range(10):
      try:
        cv2.imshow("SAMPLE?", buff[1])
      finally:
              pass
      cv2.waitKey(15)
    time.sleep(1.25)
    #cb.join()
    #cb.sleep(1.)
    #cb.terminate()
    #frame = cb.get_last()
    cb.running = False
    ###lock.acquire()
    #frame = cb.buffer[0]
    frame = buff[0]    
    #frame = buff[0]    
    frame = cb.buffer[0]
    if frame is not None:
        print('Showing frame from Thread')
        cv2.imshow('PARAMETER BUFFER?', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(500)
    #frame = buffer[0] #Global
    #if frame is not None:
    #    print('showing frame From GLOBAL')
    #    cv2.imshow('GLOBAL FRAME', frame)
        
    ###lock.release()
    time.sleep(3)
    cb.terminate()    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    print('Frame buffer test [Done]')
    cb.join()
    
    #exit(0)
```

Comment: instead of cv.waitKey(1) it should be cv2.waitKey(1). cannot submit a small edit, so putting in comments

Comment: by the way your simple fix works only if I wait for rather long time (>100 in arguments to waitkey() ). But your logic IMHO does not apply as i am not updating the highgui at a faster rate. I am simply grabbing a single frame and showing it, Right?

Comment: Adding waiting in the capturing process segfaults and errors like"saving frame  4
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
capturing frame  0
saving frame  0
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
capturing frame  1
saving frame  1
QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread
terminating thread
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
"

Comment: Sure, cv2.waitKey(). Run my code, on my setup, it suggests other possible reasons, it works fine with waitKey(1), but mine also has wait for the frame capture as suggested - your code is "starving" the task scheduler, that's like While True: ... The other threads (including that probably) have not time slot left.  As of highgui - it is updated, imshow() tries to read data but while it starts the control is switched to the other thread which is using that data and locks it.

Comment: Use cv2.waitKey() and run my code, it has that (but you may need to clean some experiments) and there are no errors.

Comment: QObject - Qt. Maybe it needs more comprehensive synchronization, see the other data exchange variants (there are some excessive copying of frames which could be commented).

BTW: "I wait for rather long time (>100 in arguments to waitkey()). "

Then that's either a thread synchronization issue or your system can't keep up reading the frames, but if that wait is in the main thread only - isn't the main thread doing nothing in that time, while the capture is working in the background (and there's 3 second sleep) - it doesn't matter in that very case.

Comment: I tried again: just cv2.waitKey(1) on the main thread is fine on my setup, even if pumping frames at full speed. I guess QT is the bug. Try to reinstall opencv with another highgui backend.